# How To Generate Pdf Stream, Or Send Post Data To Pdf Url and generate it as an html5 object?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to generate PDF in a `div` tag like this.

```
<div id="pdf">
    <object width="400" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="pdftext.pdf" id="pdf_content"></object>
</div>
```

I am still unable to  accomplish this due to my requirements.

- request using GET values must not be used.
- IFrame must not be used.
- no physical file is generated. Only strings.

I tried rendering base64 pdf byte stream using HTML 5 object but still no luck.

```
<div id = 'pdfHere'>
    <object src="data:application/pdf;base64,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" type="application/pdf" width="100%" class="internal">
        <param name="view" value="fitH" />            
    </object>
</div>
```

I have tried using plugins like pdf.js or pdfObject but this plugins won't allow me to pass POST values to the url (as far as I know).

PHP accomplished my task by doing this.
I use `header('Content-type: application/pdf')` and rendered string like this `%PDF-1.4 %âãÏÓ 5 0 obj <>stream xœÅ\ÛrÛ¶}÷Wàí¤3` but they wanted it inside a `div` tag (not iframe).

Is there any way javascript can render byte stream or plugins which I can post values to URL and render the return and put it inside a div or generate an HTML 5 pdf object?

Comment: You want to generate a pdf from html ???? but it should be not physical file ? I think I have the code for the same

Comment: I have a link where it accept post values and  returns a pdf content type. PHP processed it to make it pdf. Its easy if I wil use iframe or target='_blank' but what if i need it to be an HTML5 PDF Object?

Comment: Have you seen any where pdg embedded into html ???? or any other type of file ????

Comment: <object width="400" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="pdftext.pdf" id="pdf_content"></object> - this code works if the user has a static file. but i want to have a dynamic content.  Sending/Posting data to the URL, process and display it to the client. I don't know yet if anyone has done that.

Comment: have you tried to pass the php file name that genrates the pdf like <object width="400" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="pdfgenrator.php" id="pdf_content"></object>

Comment: Yes it works. But I need to send data to pdfgenerator.php for processing. I don't know how.

Comment: Please give me more detail how you will come to the page code if possible

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

tried to pass the php file name that genrates the pdf like `<object width="400" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="pdfgenrator.php" id="pdf_content"></object>`
And to pass data to pdfgenrator.php you have to do it before the whole page load else it will not work